# Отображение информации с другого сайта.

Tags: php, html, javascript

Всем доброго времени суток! 
Необходимо, чтобы на моем сайте высвечивалась информация с другого сайта. А именно кусок кода.

Пример:

```
<p class="user-info__account-balance"><span>
    8566.00
    </span> руб.</p>
```

Но суть в том-то, что эта информация высвечивается только для пользователей, которые залогинились.

Какими способами возможно это осуществить?

Стили css не обязательно парсить, главное, чтобы информация отображалась.

Comment: Да ты что 0_о? Не нужно стили парсить?  
Ты просто зверь, бро :)

Comment: Этот стиль будет моим перекрываться, необходимо, чтобы информация отображалась, а именно сумма. А можно по существу ответить? Почему и как?

Comment: Смог затестить, и вот код:

    $string = '<p class="user-info__account-balance"><span>
        8566.00
        </span> руб.</p>'; // Взял из примера, но нужно заменить на сорцы страницы (cURL, file_get_contents, stream, file, desc, etc...).
    preg_match('#user-info__account-balance"\s*>\s*<span\s*>\s*([\d\.]+)\s*<\/span>#', $string, $match);
    print $match ? 'Balance: ' . $match[1] . '<br />' : 'Log In, please!'; // Проверка - если найдёт, то выведет баланс; нет - попросит войти.

На этот раз регулярка работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно как-то так:

```
<?
$page = file_get_contents('your_site/file');
preg_match('#user-info__account-balance"\s*>\s*<span\s*>\s*([\d\.]+)\s*<\/span>##', $page, $match);
```

В переменной `$match[1]` будут твои цифры. Если, конечно, ты залогинен, иначе ничего не найдёшь.

Comment: regex + html => [why can't you parse html with regex](https://www.google.ru/search?q=why+can%27t+you+parse+html+with+regex), 533000 результатов

Comment: Я не проверял на валидность, я лишь смысл донёс. Валидность проверить пока не могу.

Comment: @TheDoctor, да без разницы, валиден или нет (на самом деле невалиден, вернет обрезанный тег), нельзя работать с html регэкспами.

Comment: Слышал, что с помощью скрипта можно такое выполнить или фрейма. Вот только не знаю как. Есть ли какие-нибудь другие способы спарсить информацию? Код на валидность проверял, выдает ошибку синтаксиса.

Comment: @Etki, чойта нельзя? Я постоянно парсингом всякой фигни таким образом занимаюсь, если лучшего способа нет.  
ТС, если есть доступ к DOM через JS, то вообще без проблем:

    var price = +document.querySelector('user-info__account-balance span').innerHTML;

В `price` будут цифры. Теперь точно.

Comment: @TheDoctor

> чойта нельзя? Я постоянно парсингом всякой фигни таким образом занимаюсь, если лучшего способа нет.

рад видеть вас в нашем уютном мире бесконечного рефакторинга  
потому что регэксп совпадет с идентичной конструкцией в соседней секции, даже если она скрыта через css  
потому что стоит появиться пробелу между тегами, и эта регулярка уже провалится  
потому что регулярки не парсят языки, подразумевающие вложенность

> (js-решение)

new Number / parseFloat?

Comment: @Etki, чего такой злой? Пойди выпей тёплого молочка с вискариком (алкоголь - зло!).  
Я знаю, что моя конструкция шаткая и ненадёжная (и не работающая, как оказалось), НО: лучше без сорцов нельзя сделать, да и это просто ответ, как делать, а не точный ответ "Скопипасть, вставь у себя и оно заработает!".  
Пробелы легко добавляются `\s*`, но в данном нам куске кода пробелов не было.  
Да, есть большая проблема - добавление пробела и всё посыпется, но для этого можно взять какой-нибудь парсер HTML для PHP или ещё что придумать.  
Я дал удочку, а ловить ТС должен сам.

Comment: Ребят, тут, короче, покопался на других форумах и затестил такую штуку: 

    <?php
    $ch = curl_init ("http://www.example.com/");
    $fp = fopen ("example_homepage.txt", "w");

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    fclose ($fp);
    ?>

Все данные парсятся, если залогинен из-под себя.
Но все уходит в txt файл. Теперь осталось разобраться, как вывести нужный код на сайте.

Скрипт работает на ура.

Comment: Я в правильном направлении?
P.S. Хотя ошибочка вышла.

Comment: Ты через cURL сграббил всё добро в файл, это понятно.  
Теперь выдирай оттуда это число регуляркой, строй модель DOM и вставляй оттуда, попляши с бубном...  
Направление... возможно правильное. Зачем сохранять ненужный хлам в файле, если его можно получить банально через `file_get_contents()`? А если этот хлам и правда нужен, тогда верным путём идёте, товарищЪ!

Comment: Теперь понял, в какую сторону копать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если логиниться надо, то применяй для парсинга `curl` (тут только простым советом не обойтись), а вытащить из спарсенного кода твою сумму поможет регулярка из ответа [@TheDoctor](/users/31688/thedoctor)